# I always get 0 results for queryBuilder().where().between()

Tags: android, mysql, ormlite, query-builder

ORMLite `where.between()` method in queryBuilder never works I always get 0 result even though I've inserted data successfully to the same table.  I'm using the 4.48 version of ORMLite with Android Studio.

Variable declaration inside ORMLite model class

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = "time_stamp", dataType = DataType.DATE_LONG)
Date dateValue;
```

I'm inserting data as below,

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I'm querying like below,

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date lastDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24));
Where where = dbHelper.getFeedbackDao().queryBuilder().where();
where.eq("dealID", dealId);
where.and();
where.between("time_stamp", currentDate, lastDate);
feedbacks = where.query();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Javadocs for the `Where.between(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#between(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) the parameters are:

```
public Where<T,ID> between(String columnName, Object low, Object high) throws SQLException
```

Notice that the `low` value comes first and the `high` value comes second.  This mirrors the [SQL BETWEEN operation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp).  Unfortunately, you parameters are reversed:

```
where.between("time_stamp", currentDate, lastDate);
```

Just switch `currentDate` and `lastDate` parameter order and it should work.